# Robot Framework Selenium2Library Errors

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Every Robot test or suite I run starts with these errors:

```
[12656:18380:1208/102259.167:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] 
Unknown policy: DHEEnabled
[12656:18380:1208/102259.167:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] 
Unknown policy: RC4Enabled
[12656:18380:1208/102259.168:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] 
Unknown policy: SSLVersionMin
```

I am running:

- Windows 7
- Python 3.4.4 on win32
- Robot Framework 3.0.2
- Selenium2Library 3.0.0b1

I see the policies set in the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google` but am still not able to find why these errors show when running the tests.  They do not prevent the run but just show as errors in the cmd line.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Have a look at `chrome://policy/` in Chrome.

Comment: I pulled up that page and see all 2 and they are in a status of "Unknown policy", how do I address this?

Comment: Remove the entries from the registry.